# Dynamic generated markers in leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to display custom markers on a map. The markers are created dynamically with every record that i get through API. The images are hosted elsewhere. However whenever i try to pull up the map with the markers those do not display and only a default marker shows up. I am wondering if i do something wrong with the marker set up:

```
    var dynamicIcon = []; 
    var dIcon = [];
    var weatherMarker = [];
    $.getJSON('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/box/city?bbox=1.89,49.05,2.86,48.63,10&cluster=yes', function(data)
          {
            var i=0;
            while(i < data.list.length-1)
            {
            dynamicIcon[i] = L.Icon.Default.extend({
                 options:{
                 iconURL:'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+data.list[i].weather[0].icon+'.png',
                }
                        });
            dIcon[i] = new dynamicIcon[i]();
            weatherMarker[i] = new L.marker([data.list[i].coord.lat, data.list[i].coord.lon], {icon: dIcon[i]}, {draggable:false});
            map.addLayer(weatherMarker[i]);
          }
         });
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently i was doing it wrong; like this it works:

```
       dynamicIcon[i] = new L.Icon({
         iconUrl:'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/'+data.list[i].weather[0].icon+'.png',
       });
       weatherMarker[i] = new L.marker([data.list[i].coord.lat, data.list[i].coord.lon], {
                        icon:dynamicIcon[i] });
       map.addLayer(weatherMarker[i]);
```